# How to run ECS tasks using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I recently started getting into the devops side of things and am currently working with Terraform and AWS ECS to setup a simple web server host my web applications.

Using my current Terraform config I can see my cluster being created with a service that has my task definition. I can't figure out how to run the tasks required to launch the webserver from Terraform. I can only see the capability to create the task definitions and services, but not run them. I am very new to both these technologies so I fear I might be missing something simple.

The setup I used is from an [example](https://github.com/navapbc/tf-ecs-example) I found online that I tried to follow.

TL;DR: I can create services using Terraform but can't seem to figure out how to run them.

Comment: do you want to create service? yes it is possible if you want to create service in other word to create container in ECS

Comment: No, I can create the service. I just don't understand how/whey tasks can be run?

Comment: This is a webserver that should be up and running all the time?

Comment: @MarkB yep. Right now just looking to host a simple restful web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need define an `"aws_ecs_service"` resource in Terraform and in there define how many instances of your task you want running. In the example you link, that is done in the `main.tf` file [here](https://github.com/navapbc/tf-ecs-example/blob/master/templates/basic-app/main.tf).

Comment: Yes, I got to that point, but the concept I'm struggling with is now that the service is created how do i run it? Using the aws ui when I create a task it's availabe right away. But using terraform I can only create a service and now I still need to run the task..how is that done using terraform?

Comment: An `aws_ecs_service` is a running task. See the definition: "Provides an ECS service - effectively a task that is expected to run until an error occurs or a user terminates it (typically a webserver or a database)." If it isn't running after you deploy it then you need to look at the service logs to see why it isn't able to start.

Comment: Aaah..okay that helps clarify some things for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you can run the task from terraform except running the external script or `aws-cli` from the `local-exec` provisioner.

Comment: Hmm..interesting. Why would that be? And if I have a service that's created how could I run it using the aws-cli?

Comment: You don't need to run any task inside service, when you are creating service its ECS responsibility to maintain your desired number of task running. You only have to create the service rest ECS will do its job. Also, there is another API named `run-task` you may also use it via aws cli if you don't want to create ecs service and only want task to run one time.

Comment: Adding to that, after some time, I realized tasks are ephemeral and gone once done/error. So a terraform resource wouldn't make sense (to fail on destroy, to create on apply every time? etc.).